# Wordpress Dropdown Categories All Links to Single

Tags: php, wordpress, drop-down-menu, categories

I'm having an issue where, even though the page renders originally with "All" selected in the dropdown, if you go to a category (renders fine) and then back to "All" in the dropdown, you see a single post. This is instead of the originally displayed page with all of the categories. I need the page to basically render the same page for "All" regardless. Any thoughts?

```
wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_all=All&hide_empty=0&show_count=0&orderby=name&echo=0');
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar post on WPSE last week and it seems that the two might be related. For convenience, here is the post

Here is a variation of the code that you use. I'm using [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) here to achieve the same goal. I had to adjust my code slightly to make it acceptable for your need.

There are a however other modifications you have to make for this to work. When you select the `All Categories` option, you will be taken to a page that will display what ever you need to display. This page you will have to **manually** create

There is no index archive pages in Wordpress as you might know. (*Check out [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/156275/31545) I have done on the same subject*). What this means is, `domain.com/category/` returns a 404.

So, to make this all work, you'll have to make a copy of page.php, rename it to something like page-category.php (see the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) on how to create custom page templates), open it up, create your [custom query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to display what you would like to display when this page is visited

You now need to create your page in the back end. I would suggest that you use the slug `category` so that when you visit `domain.com/category/`, this page would be displayed. (*Just remember, you **cannot** create child pages for this page, it will break the hierarchy*). I have also made the code to go to `domain.com/category/` when `All Categories` is selected

Apart from that, the code should work fine. You just need to check the URL structures maybe, and also set the parameters in `get_categories()` to suite your needs. Here is the drop down code.

```
<select name="event-dropdown" onchange='document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'> 
<option value=""><?php echo esc_attr(__('Select Category')); ?></option> 

<?php 
$option = '<option value="' . get_option('home') . '/category/">All Categories</option>'; // change category to your custom page slug
$categories = get_categories(); 
foreach ($categories as $category) {
$option .= '<option value="'.get_option('home').'/category/'.$category->slug.'">';
$option .= $category->cat_name;
$option .= ' ('.$category->category_count.')';
$option .= '</option>';
}
echo $option;
?>
</select>
```

**EDIT**

I actually had an idea here that will come in handy. I've recently done an answer on displaying all categories in a list with all post titles under the specific category. This same idea can be used in your page-category.php template.

When a user selects the `All Categories` option, they will be taken to this page which will list all categories and post title.

Here is the complete code: (*for an explanation of the code, see my post [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/145960/31545)*)

In your functions.php

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'publish_new_post', 10, 3 );

function publish_new_post() {
   delete_transient( 'category_list' );
}
```

In your template where you need to display your list

```
<?php
if ( false === ( $q = get_transient( 'category_list' ) ) ) {

    $args = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args); 

    $q = array();

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) { 

        $query->the_post(); 

        $a = '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'">' . get_the_title() .'</a>';

        $categories = get_the_category();

        foreach ( $categories as $key=>$category ) {

            $b = '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->cat_ID ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';    

        }

        $q[$b][] = $a; // Create an array with the category names and post titles
    }


    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();

set_transient( 'category_list', $q, 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
}

foreach ($q as $key=>$values) {
        echo $key;

        echo '<ul>';
            foreach ($values as $value){
                echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
            }
        echo '</ul>';
    }


?>
```